# python : passing values between class and outside constructor

Tags: python, class

I am trying to pass values from a class to another one, so my passing of values between the constructors of the first and second class work fine. But whenever I try to access some values from the class constructor its doesn't look as that variable is taken by the method.

Here is the file named file1.py which contains class Foo:

```
from file2 import *
class Bar():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.var = foo.h
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print(self.var)
    def function():
        print" the values is : ",self.var
    function()
b = Bar(Foo())
```

Then here is my file2.py code:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 6
        self.y = 2
        self.h = self.x+self.y
```

My problem that whenever I try to get values inside function() I'm stuck in this part. The error output :

```
print" the values is : ",self.var
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: The function `def` needs to be indented, else it's not part of the class definition.

Comment: @Jens - I assume that's a copy-paste error, as the code wouldn't compile at all like that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I don't know that about the `def function()`, for the `__init__` I agree.

Comment: Most of the code needs to be indented.  Just paste the code, highlight it, and hit Ctrl-k.  Don't indent some lines to put them in a block, but leave the rest where they are.  Highlighting and hitting Ctrl-k will do all of the work for you.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens? "stuck" isn't enough. Is there a stack trace saying `name 'self' is not defined`? Give us the exact error you see!

Comment: I mean in general, with no indented line after `class Bar():`. The code blocks' indentation surely differ from the originals'.

Comment: Function `function` misses the `self` parameter: `def function(self):`. Furthermore, why do you call `function` during class initialization?

Comment: sorry i dunno why the indentation was removed but now its seem okay.
also i already post the error output by the prompt interpreter

Comment: In addition to a missing `self` as Jens said, you're calling `function()` immediately, before the class has been instantiated, so there is no self. If you want it not to be attached to an instance, make it a static method (at which point `self.var` no longer makes sense to refer to).

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, `function` is an instance method so it needs a `self` parameter. Second, you are calling `function()` as part of the class definition and I have no idea why. I think its supposed to be a member method and it should be called after the instance is created.

```
from file2 import *
class Bar():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.var = foo.h
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print(self.var)
    def function(self):
        print " the values is : ",self.var

b = Bar(Foo())
b.function()
```

Comment: actually i got that i must use self with function but i type only this two lines in bottom of my code
b = Bar(Foo())
function()
i forget to mentioned b.function()
thanks!!!